# R : pushing data to matrix giving strange behaviour

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap

Hi I'm pushing data into a matrix so I can create a heatmap. The code I am using identical to what is published here (http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/heatmaps_in_r.html). For some of my datasets, when I push the data into the matrix format I am getting strange behaviour in that some of the values are changing. Some of my datasets work fine but others do not and I am unsure what the primary differences are that is underlying this strange behaviour.

### Example code;

```
data <- read.csv("mydata.txt", sep="\t", header =TRUE) 
rnames <- data[,1] 
mat_data <- data.matrix(data[,2:ncol(data)]) 
rownames(mat_data) <- rnames
```

---

Now example dataframes..

```
head(data)
1        1.108029        0.42        0.19        0.04        0.47       -0.08        0.47        0.04        0.10
2        1.108029        0.34        0.40        0.25        0.56       -0.08       -0.06        0.11        0.20
3        1.121099         0.1       -0.45        0.11       -0.22       -0.07       -0.40        0.24       -0.17
4        1.123857        0.26       -0.15        0.15        0.31         0.2       -0.24       -0.27        0.40
5        1.129303        0.11        0.13        0.01       -0.11        0.38        0.29       -0.15       -0.18
6        1.135904         0.4        0.07        0.11        0.03         0.6       -0.32        0.14       -0.12

head(mat_data)
             tg_q2_rep_A tg_q2_rep_B tg_q2_rep_C tg_q2_rep_D tg_q4_rep_A tg_q4_rep_B tg_q4_rep_C tg_q4_rep_D
1.10802929          70        0.19        0.04        0.47           5        0.47        0.04        0.10
1.1080293           65        0.40        0.25        0.56           5       -0.06        0.11        0.20
1.12109912          49       -0.45        0.11       -0.22           4       -0.40        0.24       -0.17
1.12385707          62       -0.15        0.15        0.31          53       -0.24       -0.27        0.40
1.12930344          50        0.13        0.01       -0.11          65        0.29       -0.15       -0.18
1.1359041           69        0.07        0.11        0.03          69       -0.32        0.14       -0.12
```

You can see the rownames have had numbers appended to the ends and the first data for tg_q2_rep_A and tg_q4_rep_A have been changed.

If anyone can suggest how to approach this I'd appreciate it. I've been trying to figure this out for days :/

EDIT

**As requested ..**

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   137 obs. of  33 variables:
 $ CpG_id.chr.pos.: num  1.11 1.11 1.12 1.12 1.13 ...
 $ tg_q2_rep_A    : Factor w/ 75 levels "-0.01","-0.02",..: 70 65 49 62 50 69 71 63 57 7 ...
 $ tg_q2_rep_B    : num  0.19 0.4 -0.45 -0.15 0.13 0.07 0.5 -0.33 0.23 -0.22 ...
 $ tg_q2_rep_C    : num  0.04 0.25 0.11 0.15 0.01 0.11 0.16 0.03 0.23 -0.32 ...
 $ tg_q2_rep_D    : num  0.47 0.56 -0.22 0.31 -0.11 0.03 0.31 0.21 0 0.06 ...
 $ tg_q4_rep_A    : Factor w/ 73 levels "-0.04","-0.05",..: 5 5 4 53 65 69 50 53 59 46 ...
 $ tg_q4_rep_B    : num  0.47 -0.06 -0.4 -0.24 0.29 -0.32 0.07 -0.23 0.1 -0.09 ...
 $ tg_q4_rep_C    : num  0.04 0.11 0.24 -0.27 -0.15 0.14 0.14 0.36 0.1 -0.05 ...
 $ tg_q4_rep_D    : num  0.1 0.2 -0.17 0.4 -0.18 -0.12 0.15 0.18 -0.21 -0.14 ...
 $ tg_q6_rep_A    : Factor w/ 79 levels "-0.02","-0.03",..: 46 3 7 67 65 77 64 61 41 12 ...
 $ tg_q6_rep_B    : Factor w/ 87 levels "-0.01","-0.03",..: 68 79 34 11 82 1 63 1 36 32 ...
 $ tg_q6_rep_C    : num  0.22 0.5 -0.32 0.13 0.24 0.25 0.35 0.07 0.01 -0.44 ...
 $ tg_q6_rep_D    : Factor w/ 82 levels "-0.04","-0.05",..: 55 50 27 74 71 68 73 61 5 31 ...
 $ tg_q8_rep_A    : Factor w/ 73 levels "-0.01","-0.02",..: 49 9 2 52 45 50 13 55 48 9 ...
 $ tg_q8_rep_B    : num  0.05 0.07 -0.31 0.02 0 -0.33 0.03 -0.05 0.08 0.1 ...
 $ tg_q8_rep_C    : num  0.35 0.5 -0.06 -0.1 0.24 -0.45 -0.27 0.1 0.15 -0.29 ...
 $ tg_q8_rep_D    : num  0.15 0.08 -0.08 0.31 0.28 0.43 0.41 0.25 -0.05 -0.04 ...
 $ tg_w2_rep_A    : Factor w/ 72 levels "-0.01","-0.02",..: 49 16 24 66 60 62 62 68 52 49 ...
 $ tg_w2_rep_B    : num  0.11 0.24 -0.03 -0.43 0.67 -0.13 0.05 -0.4 -0.13 -0.18 ...
 $ tg_w2_rep_C    : num  0 0.33 -0.09 0 0.12 -0.35 0.06 0.33 0.15 -0.19 ...
 $ tg_w2_rep_D    : num  -0.04 0 -0.03 0.44 0.04 0.23 0.28 0.19 -0.21 -0.17 ...
 $ tg_w4_rep_A    : Factor w/ 69 levels "-0.0","-0.01",..: 55 58 53 50 52 67 68 63 27 8 ...
 $ tg_w4_rep_B    : num  0.29 0.63 -0.37 0.09 0.22 -0.21 0.1 -0.14 -0.04 -0.09 ...
 $ tg_w4_rep_C    : num  0.09 0.13 -0.08 0.17 0.15 -0.33 0 0.38 0.1 -0.62 ...
 $ tg_w4_rep_D    : num  0.11 0.33 -0.32 0.41 -0.1 0.07 0.23 0.22 0.1 0.06 ...
 $ tg_w6_rep_A    : Factor w/ 74 levels "-0.01","-0.02",..: 56 45 4 69 59 47 2 40 47 12 ...
 $ tg_w6_rep_B    : num  0.07 0.13 -0.14 0.15 0.13 -0.17 0.33 0.12 0.07 -0.15 ...
 $ tg_w6_rep_C    : num  0.13 0.22 0.31 0.08 0.16 -0.33 -0.05 0.43 0.43 -0.06 ...
 $ tg_w6_rep_D    : num  0.28 0.11 -0.2 0.66 -0.18 0.16 0.26 0.27 0.06 -0.02 ...
 $ tg_w8_rep_A    : Factor w/ 67 levels "-0.01","-0.02",..: 52 40 37 44 48 61 48 53 39 63 ...
 $ tg_w8_rep_B    : num  0.3 0.09 -0.22 -0.1 0.14 -0.25 0.1 -0.49 0.19 0.15 ...
 $ tg_w8_rep_C    : num  0.23 0.27 0.11 -0.25 0.17 -0.13 0.23 0.47 0.33 -0.09 ...
 $ tg_w8_rep_D    : num  -0.04 0.1 -0.25 0.37 -0.09 0.18 0.26 0.2 -0.35 -0.11 ...
```

---

Comment: Data that changes when coerced to matrix suggest part of the data is factor. Please post str(.) results from all of the input. You may want to use 'colClasses' during the `read.table` call.

Comment: I see there is different levels... I have some values as 'None' in the array.. I suppose R is removing/excluding these values!! Thanks for the useful command!!

Comment: Not just "removing" levels but also probably scrambling the results, since factor levels are alpha sorted and so "1" is closer to "100" than is "2".

Comment: Yep removing the 'None' values fixed the problem.. Thanks BonedDust!!

Comment: Where'd the header on `mat_data` come from?  I was just going to work through this but noticed they just magically appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your rownames is that they aren't unique. R requires unique identifiers for each row, and you have multiple rows with the same value in the data.frame "data". When you try to force it to make the values in that first column rownames, it's trying to make them unique, and it looks as though it's rounding some numbers to accomplish that.

I'm not entirely certain what's going on with columns tg_q2_rep_A and tg_q4_rep_A, but it looks as though those values have been converted to ranks. That can happen if the class of those columns in your original data.frame, data, was "factor" rather than "numeric". Try this to check the classes:

```
sapply(data, class)
```

If you've got a mixture of numbers and letters in that column, for example, R will set the data class as factor by default. When you convert those columns to numeric format, which is what data.matrix() does, the output will be the rank of that factor.

I didn't get the same problem for those two columns when I copied and pasted your data into a csv file and loaded it into R, but I'm guessing that you haven't given us all the data there. My first step to figure this out would be to check the classes of the columns.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful response. Problem solved.. I foolishly had 'None' values in the array so everything was getting scrambled...